# RxAndroid with Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-android

I have interface

```
 @GET("/data, 2.5/forecast/daily")
   Observable<MultilingualWeather> getWeatherByIdWithMultilingual(
    @Query("id") String id,
    @Query("lang") String lang,
    @Query("appid") String appid);
```

MainActivity be called up in the following configuration

```
 Retrofit retrofit_weather = new Retrofit.Builder().
        baseUrl(BASE_URL).
        addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).
        addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()).
        build();

GetWeatherForLocation getWeather = retrofit_weather.create(GetWeatherForLocation.class);

Observable<MultilingualWeather> call_observable = getWeather.
            getWeatherByIdWithMultilingual(
            CITY_ID,
            LANG,
            KEY
    );

    subscription = call_observable.subscribe(subscriber);
```

The following file dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1'
```

}

and after all this takes off exception

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.alex.weatherclient, PID: 16658 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "retrofit.CallAdapter retrofit.CallAdapter$Factory.get(java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.annotation.Annotation[], retrofit.Retrofit)"
```

Comment: Have you accidentally used different versions for any of your retrofit dependencies by any chance? [Possibly related Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077292/abstractmethoderror-when-using-rxjavacalladapterfactory-on-retrofit-2).

Comment: yep have the same issue, i ll try to change to beta2 and see if this resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Replace in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1'
```

on

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like a typo. Your interface uses `getWeatherByIdWithMultilingual` and your code uses `getWeatherByIdWithMultilingual2`